# JavaFX action event statement execution order

Tags: java, javafx

```
public class MainController {
@FXML
public Button browse_report;
@FXML
public Button browse_directory;
@FXML
public Button export;
@FXML
public Button close;
@FXML
public Label report;
@FXML
public Label directory;
@FXML
public Label processing;
@FXML
public TextField report_text;
@FXML
public TextField directory_text;
@FXML
public ProgressBar pg = new ProgressBar();



public void closeButton(ActionEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
}

public void getReport(ActionEvent e) {
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    File file=fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    report_text.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
}

public void getDirectory(ActionEvent e) {
    DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();
    File file =dc.showDialog(null);
    directory_text.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

}

public void Export(ActionEvent e) {

    pg.setProgress(-1);
    foo();
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Spreadsheet Generated", ButtonType.CLOSE);
    alert.showAndWait();
    pg.setProgress(1);
}
```

The above Export() method, when executed on button click,appears to run the method statements out of order. The progress bar animation does not display until after the alert window pops up. How can I correct this?

Comment: What is `foo()` standing in for? Is it some process that takes a long time to run?

Comment: It's an instantiation of a new class that goes on to call methods to convert a text file into an excel file. It takes about 5 seconds because the text file is large and stored on a network drive. I really just want the gui to make it look like its thinking for those 5 seconds so the user doesn't think it froze or isn't doing anything.

Comment: So you need to do that on a background thread. If you run that on the FX Application thread, you prevent that thread from rendering the UI (until you effectively yield control of it with `showAndWait()`)

Comment: Thank you. I tried that (admittedly I 'm not very familiar with threading). I set it up as a task that ran in a new thread. But when set up that way, the method seems to start of the new thread and then immediately launch the alert window without waiting for the thread to finish. How can I set it up so the alertbox pops up only after the thread finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `foo()` method takes a long time to run, what is happening is that you are blocking the FX Application Thread, which prevents it from performing its usual duties, such as rendering the UI. So while the statements are (of course) executed in the order you write them, i.e. the `progressProperty` of `pg` is set to `-1`, then `foo()` is executed, then the `Alert` is shown, you won't actually *see* the results of those in the UI until the whole process completes (or, actually, in this case until you relinquish control of the FX Application Thread by calling `showAndWait()`).

The basic way to solve this is to run `foo()` in a background thread. If there is UI-related code you want to perform when that completes, the best way to do that is to use a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and use its `onSucceeded` handler to perform the UI code at the end. So in general you do something like this:

```
public void Export(ActionEvent e) {

    pg.setProgress(-1);
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            foo();
            return null ;
        }
    };
    task.setOnSucceeded(evt -> {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Spreadsheet Generated", ButtonType.CLOSE);
        alert.showAndWait();
        pg.setProgress(1);

    });
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```